# A way to describe the following triplet

Tags: soft-question

so first of all the tittle I think is very poor, so I apologize about that.

I am working on a homework set for homology, and when I computed the image of a boundary map I got this: $(a-b,2b-c,2c)$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. I see that the first entry can be anything I want, and the last one can be any even number, but the middle one has to have the same parity as $c$. I just need a cleaner way to re-write this.

For example, $(a-b,2b)$ is just $\mathbb{Z}\oplus 2\mathbb{Z}$.